# Call a variable without create instance of object

Tags: java, oop

I've searched about calling a variable without creating an instance of object over StackOverflow and found the answer was the *use `static` keyword to declare variable and you will be able to call that variable in extended class without creating instance of that class* but it didn't work for me. Here is what I've tried -

```
abstract public class Flower{
      private static int petals;
      public void setPetals(int petals){
          this.petals;
      }
}
```

So I called the `setPetals` method from another class. I have attached as screenshot that class. How do I call that petals variable in LotusFlower class?
[image]

Comment: It's `private`.

Comment: Your `setPetal()` is not `static`, and you call this, not accessing your `static` variable `petals`... So add `static` to the method, too...

Comment: I supose you have your good reasons to do this, but it doesn't seem to me a good example. If you have several subclasses of `Flower`, and every one of them sets a static value, the preivous one will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to improve on:

1. The `setPetals` method definition is not static and you are not actually setting the value of petals there:

   ```
   public static void setPetals(int petals){
       this.petals = petals;
   }
   ```
2. The petals variable is static and can be referenced from `setPetals` instead as :

   ```
   Flower.petals = petals;
   ```
3. Further you can use the `setPetals` method from another class as :

   ```
   Flower.setPetals(100);
   ```

Comment: Look out: `petals` is private and canot be directly referenced from another class.

Comment: @LittleSanti the reference I made was within the `setPetals`. updated the answer to call that out.